# How to access array elements of pointers

Tags: c++, pointers

How can I access elements from my Node pointer array? The cout at the bottom returns an address "0xb7738ff4". Even if I make a constructor and set each element to NULL, I cannot modify any of them later on.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Node
{
    public:
    char character;
};
class Tree
{
    public:
    Node* nodes[26];
};
int main() {
 Tree t;
 //t.nodes[0]->character = 'a';
 cout << "\"" << (t.nodes[0]) << "\"";
}
```

http://ideone.com/XvLme9

Comment: nodes is a pointer to an array...

Comment: `nodes` is an array of pointers.  Using `t->` is wrong because `t` is not a pointer, using `t.` is correct.

Comment: and where is the constructor?? and what you want it to print?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`t.nodes[0]` is returning a `Node*` pointer.  You are passing that pointer as-is to `cout`, that is why it is printing a memory address (and a random one at that, because you are not initializing the array).  If you want to print the `character` of a node, you have to dereference the `Node*` pointer, exactly like your commented out code is doing (which is the correct way to do it):

```
t.nodes[0]->character
```

You just have to make sure that `nodes[0]` returns a valid pointer to a real `Node` object to begin with:

```
Tree t;
t.nodes[0] = new Node; // <-- here
t.nodes[0]->character = 'a';
std::cout << "\"" << t.nodes[0]->character << "\"" << std::endl;
```

Don't forget to `delete` the node when you are done using it.  `Tree` should have a destructor that frees the nodes it owns.

Try something more like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>

class Node
{
public:
    char character;

    Node(char c = 0);
};

class Tree
{
private:
    Node* nodes[26];
    int count;
public:
    Tree();
    ~Tree();
    Node* add(char c);
    Node* get(int idx);
};

Node::Node(char c)
    : character(c)
{
}

Tree::Tree()
    : count(0)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 26; ++i)
        nodes[i] = NULL;
}

Tree::~Tree()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
        delete nodes[i];
}

Node* Tree::add(char c)
{
    if (count == 26)
        throw std::runtime_error("nodes array is at its max capacity");

    Node *node = new Node(c);
    nodes[count++] = node;
    return node;
}

Node* Tree::get(int idx)
{
    if ((idx < 0) || (idx >= count))
        throw std::out_of_range("invalid index");
    return nodes[idx];
}

int main()
{
    Tree t;
    t.add('a');
    std::cout << "\"" << t.get(0)->character << "\"" << std::endl;
}
```

With that said, you should use `std::list` or `std::forward_list` instead of writing your own tree class:

```
#include <list>

int main()
{
    std::list<char> l;
    l.push_back('a');
    std::cout << "\"" << l.front() << "\"" << std::endl;
}
```

Or:

```
#include <list>

class Node
{
public:
    char character;
    // other things here...

    Node(char c = 0);
    Node(const Node &src);
    Node& operator=(const Node &rhs);
};

Node::Node(char c)
    : character(c)
{ 
}

Node::Node(const Node &src)
    : character(src.character)
{
}

Node& Node::operator=(const Node &rhs)
{
    character = src.character;
    return *this;
}

int main()
{
    std::list<Node> l;
    l.push_back('a');
    std::cout << "\"" << l.front().character << "\"" << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me, I made those changes but it segfaults: http://codepad.org/xsH60WVD why is this?

Comment: You did not make the changes I told you to make.  Look more carefully at my example.  I told you to `new` a `Node` object and store it in the array, but you `new`'ed a `Tree` object instead (and are not `delete`'ing it), and are still not initializing the array at all. You are segfaulting when you try to dereference an uninitialized `Node*` pointer.

Comment: Thanks for helping me, this really helps. I finally got it to work. I won't implement the whole thing yet with private variables and proper destuctors, but thanks again http://codepad.org/n9jIC3XS